# Evaluate variable content as field name in data frame

Tags: r

Querying data like this:

```
test = data.frame(a = 1:4,b = 1:4)
subset(test, a < 4) # Works
subset(test, b < 4) # Works
```

However, trying something that works more dynamically is not working

```
test = data.frame(a = 1:4,b = 1:4)
field = 'a'
subset(test, field < 4) # Not working
```

I would like to query based on the `field` contents rather than the field column.

Comment: You could do `test[ test[[field]] < 4, ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible and it's sometimes very useful! You can use `get()`:

```
test = data.frame(a = 1:4, b = 1:4)
field = 'a'
subset(test, get(field) < 4)
```

This function gets object with a given name in the argument value.

See [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html).